Как отключить боковые поля в PyQT5?
Мне нужно отключить боковые поля у окна PyQT, которые могут менять цвет объектов под этим окном
если вы всмотритесь в это окно над однотонным белым фоном, вы можете увидеть как они накладывают еле заметную тень
код окна:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    win = QWidget()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()

